# angular 6 children route components is not loading?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have a little issue.

I have app and Ido this in angular 6 and I am using children routes

as like this

```
{
        path:'pages', component:DatePagesComponent,
        children : [
            {path:'404', component:Error404Component},
            {path:'500', component:Error500Component}
        ]
}
```

and my html looks like

```
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/pages/404']">404</a></li>
<li [routerLinkActive]="['active']"><a [routerLink]="['/pages/500']">500</a></li>
```

and it fine loads route with url but always load to this `component:DatePagesComponent`

If I click to 404 than page url changes but not the change to components router

and I am writing

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

into my `app.components.html` file

Can you please tell me what is issue this and how to resolve it.

Comment: no show error in console

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to write `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to your `DatePagesComponent`'s *html* file. This will let your child routes which are associated to the `DatePagesComponent` work.

Comment: Thanks. i learned an important thing from your answer :
already i thought that an angular app can only have one <router-outlet></router-outlet>